# How to fix this error and select from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, where-clause

I have a question about listing tables and I don't understand my error. It says to
List the companyname, division, city of employers associated with interviews scheduled for 19951.

I'm trying to list the records based on the qtrcode found in interview table.

I have this code:

```
SELECT companyname, division, city
FROM employer
WHERE interview.qtrcode = '%19951%';

ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'interview.qtrcode' in 'where clause'
```

Table should look like this and havent got any output due to this error.

```
+------------------------------+------------------+------------------+
| companyname                  | division         | city             |
+------------------------------+------------------+------------------+
| Acme Information Source      | Customer Support | Cleveland        |
| Braddock Information Assoc.  | Payroll          | Boston           |
| Ajax Software, Inc.          | Production       | Berkeley         |
| Ajax Software, Inc.          | RandD            | Berkeley         |
| Bay Software Inc.            | Production       | Berkeley         |
| Vegas Programming and Design | Development      | Las Vegas        |
| Mountainside Magic Software  | Management       | Colorado Springs |
| Mountainside Magic Software  | Customer Support | Colorado Springs |
+------------------------------+------------------+------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

INTERVIEW table:

```
+----+------------+------------------------------+------------------+-------+---------+------+-------+----------+
| ID | Date       | Companyname                  | division         | Qtr.  | $ offer | Hrs. | List? | jobdesc  |
+----+------------+------------------------------+------------------+-------+---------+------+-------+----------+
|  1 | 1995-06-01 | Acme Information Source      | Customer Support | 19951 |   12.00 |   40 | y     | Job Desc |
|  2 | 1995-06-01 | Braddock Information Assoc.  | Payroll          | 19951 |   10.75 |   40 | n     | Job Desc |
|  3 | 1995-06-30 | Ajax Software, Inc.          | Production       | 19951 |   11.00 |   40 | y     | Job Desc |
|  4 | 1995-06-30 | Ajax Software, Inc.          | RandD            | 19951 |   11.50 |   40 | y     | Job Desc |
|  5 | 1995-07-01 | Bay Software Inc.            | Production       | 19951 |   11.75 |   20 | y     | Job Desc |
|  6 | 1995-08-01 | Vegas Programming and Design | Development      | 19951 |   11.00 |   40 | n     | Job Desc |
|  7 | 1995-08-01 | Mountainside Magic Software  | Management       | 19951 |   11.50 |   20 | y     | Job Desc |
|  8 | 1995-08-02 | Mountainside Magic Software  | Customer Support | 19951 |   10.75 |   40 | y     | Job Desc |
|  9 | 1995-12-01 | Cameron Industries           | Management       | 19953 |   13.25 |   35 | n     | Job Desc |
| 10 | 1995-12-02 | Cameron Industries           | Customer Support | 19953 |   13.00 |   35 | n     | Job Desc |
| 11 | 1995-12-04 | CCC Software                 | Production       | 19953 |   11.50 |   40 | n     | Job Desc |
| 12 | 1996-01-21 | DC Security Applications     | RandD            | 19953 |   11.50 |   30 | n     | Job Desc |
| 13 | 1996-02-01 | Davis-Klein Software         | RandD            | 19953 |   11.25 |   20 | n     | Job Desc |
| 14 | 1996-02-02 | Flordia Software Designs     | RandD            | 19953 |   11.75 |   30 | n     | Job Desc |
| 15 | 1996-07-01 | Rochester Software Design    | Development      | 19961 |   12.00 |   30 | n     | Job Desc |
| 16 | 1996-07-01 | Focused Applications, Inc.   | Production       | 19961 |   12.00 |   30 | y     | Job Desc |
| 17 | 1996-08-01 | Georgia Software Design      | RandD            | 19961 |   11.75 |   40 | y     | Job Desc |
| 18 | 1996-08-08 | ApplDesign                   | RandD            | 19961 |   11.50 |   30 | y     | Job Desc |
| 19 | 1996-08-11 | Long Island Apps, Inc.       | Development      | 19961 |   12.25 |   40 | y     | Job Desc |
| 20 | 1997-01-01 | Jersey Computer Services     | Customer Support | 19963 |   12.50 |   35 | n     | Job Desc |
| 21 | 1997-01-01 | Flordia Software Designs     | Development      | 19963 |   12.75 |   30 | n     | Job Desc |
| 22 | 1997-01-31 | Manhattan-Made Software      | Customer Support | 19963 |   12.50 |   40 | y     | Job Desc |
| 23 | 1997-02-01 | Manhattan-Made Software      | Payroll          | 19963 |   13.25 |   40 | y     | Job Desc |
| 24 | 1997-03-24 | Nantucket Applications, Inc. | RandD            | 19964 |   13.00 |   40 | y     | Job Desc |
| 25 | 1997-03-31 | PennState Programming, Inc.  | Management       | 19964 |   13.00 |   40 | y     | Job Desc |
| 26 | 1997-04-20 | Sandy Hook Software          | Development      | 19964 |   12.75 |   35 | n     | Job Desc |
| 27 | 1997-04-22 | Buffalo Software Assoc.      | Payroll          | 19964 |   12.75 |   35 | y     | Job Desc |
| 28 | 1997-05-01 | Virginia Software Industries | Production       | 19964 |   13.75 |   40 | n     | Job Desc |
+----+------------+------------------------------+------------------+-------+---------+------+-------+----------+
```

28 rows in set (0.00 sec)

EMPLOYER table:

```
|   companyname                    | division         | address                   | city             | statecode | zipcode |
| Acme Information Source        | Customer Support | 132 Commerical Way        | Cleveland        | OH        |   44234 |
| Ajax Software, Inc.            | RandD            | 2421 West Industrial Way  | Berkeley         | CA        |   94710 |
```

Comment: Is there a second table that you need to join such as an interview table?

Comment: Is interview a different table or it should be employer there?

Comment: basically Interview.qtrcode is from another table and that table was not included in the query.

1) when you use wildcard you have to use LIKE '%value%' for non-numeric data type but if it's a numeric data type then like is not applicable.

2) interivew.qtrcode is from another table then use JOIN clause

Comment: The interview is a different table apart from employer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

Your table is named employer, you can't acces qtrcode from interview.

You either join the interview table or the mistake is just have interview where you should have employer

IF this is the case you should have LIKE instead of =:

```
SELECT companyname, division, city
FROM employer
WHERE employer.qtrcode LIKE '%19951%';
```

Having a table interview you should have something like this:

```
SELECT companyname, division, city
FROM employer, interview
WHERE employer.id = interview.employer_id 
      AND interview.qtrcode LIKE '%19951%';
```

EDIT:

Not having an id in employer, in order to get the city you have to do:

```
SELECT interview.companyname, interview.division, employer.city
FROM employer, interview
WHERE employer.Companyname = interview.Companyname                   
      AND interview.qtrcode LIKE '%19951%';
```

This works, but you really should have an id on the employer table and not duplicate employer data on interview table.

You should have a employer_id foreign key in interview table and if you need information from the employer table you get it through this id.

Comment: The code gives me ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'employer.qtrcode' in 'where clause' How do I join the interview table?

Comment: Then you should join the interview table, but you have to join it with employer by some kind of id. If you want additional help, you should add the tables schema to your question.

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight. I added an additional query that is similar to the one you should do

Comment: ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'companyname' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: `SELECT companyname, division, city
    FROM interview
    WHERE qtrcode LIKE '%19951%';` isn't sufficient?

Comment: well, it says its unknown column city in field list.

Comment: you are going to have to do it by company name, but you really should have an id in the employer table and a column in interview as a foreign key. but i'll update my answer

Comment: Thank u so much i finally got it.

Comment: It worked, but you really should have an id on the employer table and not duplicate employer data on interview table. You should have a employer_id foreign key in interview table and if you need information from the employer table you get it through this id.